# reactjs setState not changing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have a function(onClickAddSection),  when its called, it should set the state to empty string but it doesn't do that at all.
Please take a look at the code and tell me what im doing wrong thank you.

```
class AddNewSectionForm extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        sectionName: '',
        validation:false
    };
    this.onSectionNameChange = this.onSectionNameChange.bind(this);
    this.onClickAddSection = this.onClickAddSection.bind(this);

}

onSectionNameChange(event) {
    if(this.state.validation==false){
        this.setState({validation:true});
    }
    this.setState({sectionName: event.target.value});
}

onClickAddSection(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.saveSection(this.state.sectionName);
    this.setState({sectionName:'',validation:false});
}

render() {
    return (
            <div>
                <TextInput name="newSection" label="Section Name :"
                           onChange={this.onSectionNameChange}
                           value={this.state.sectionName}
                           error = {this.state.validation==true&& this.state.sectionName.length==0?'Enter Section Name':''}/>
                <AddCloseButtons add = {this.onClickAddSection}
                                 close = {this.props.closeCharm}
                                 />
            </div>
    );
}
```

}

the onClickAddSection function doesn't set the sectionName back to ''.

AddCloseButton:

```
const AddCloseButtons = ({add,close}) => {
return (
    <div className="form-group">
        <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{width: '40%', border:'solid black 1px'}} onClick={add}>Add</button>
        <button className="btn btn-secondary" style={{width: '40%', float: 'right',border:'solid black 1px'}} onClick={close}>Close</button>
    </div>);
```

};

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with what you mean that is isn't changing? Do you know from a console.log, or is there some other specific result you are looking for that isn't happening?

Comment: Here the whole point of the component is to add a section with a name.
Here i hav TextInput component, onChange method on that component changes the state of the current component using function "onSectionNameChange". That works fine.
but after i add a section with the name that user typed, i am setting the sectionName  in the state to empty string inside the onClickAddSection function. that doesnt work

Comment: its not setting the state back to empty string after i add the section.

Comment: does it get inside the function at all? how does AddCloseButtons  look a like?

Comment: i added the component to the main question. Please take a look

Comment: does your onClickAddSection get called when you click Add button?

Comment: yes coz it adds the section perfectly fine but then it doesnt reset the state back to empty string. the setState in that function doesnt work. and i dont know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Redux? if so, this.props.saveSection makes any Ajax Call?. If so, could be that you update the local state with setState and then your Ajax response re updates it the received value?

Comment: i detached this component from redux and the setState worked fine. i dont understand what wrong i was doing.
i must pointout that i am getting a state mutation error also.
this is coz i have an Object which has a bunch of arrays nested inside it.
then i just used Object.assign({},survey) just for the very top Object and pushed all other arrys into the new Survey. Can this Be a reason for this?

Comment: I would suggest you to try this: 
  storedState = this.state.sectionName;
    this.setState({sectionName:'',validation:false},()=>{this.props.saveSection(storedState);});

Comment: when i just update the top level component without updating the redux store, it works fine. but if i update it, it throwing some weird bugs. this is probably because im mutating the state. il fix that and try if and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Just try and see the functional version of `setState`.

```
this.setState(function (state, props) {
 return {
  sectionName:'',
  validation:false
 }
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work. Its probably because of the redux

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you click the button, `onSectionNameChange` and `onClickAddSection` happen at the same time and will have conflict (because the name is set to blank means its name is being changed ^^), so how about not setting state for sectionName in `onSectionNameChange`:

```
onSectionNameChange(event) {
    if(this.state.validation==false){
        this.setState({validation:true});
    }
    //this.setState({sectionName: event.target.value});
}
```

I guess so, please post here some errors if any, thanks

Comment: onSectionNameChange happens when user enters something in the input field, 
where as onClickAddSection happens when the user clicks the add button, I could be wrong but do you think they happen at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I think so, at some point, when the value is set to BLANK '', that may happen ^^ because the nature of javascript is being asynchronous (even the setState will not take effect immediately) Besides, on React page, many actions may happen at the same time, even for actions of 1 same element, too. If you think that is logic, please consider giving my an up-vote, although it's not accepted, thanks